# How to make object orbit from behind to front?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, canvas

Is it possible to make an object orbit around another object that goes from behind and then to the front?

I've seen it being done with rotation animations that do a full 360 around the perimeter, but was wondering if it was possible to do it at an angle.

I couldn't find any resources that could do this, so I've included an image example of what I want to accomplish. The red line would be an object orbiting the blue circle.

Thanks so much - I really appreciate the help!

[image: orbit]

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: Suggestion: First of all, see if you can get something to move around in a circle. (A circle on a canvas shouldn't be too difficult). Then change it's path to an oval. Add in a planet, then change the drawing order based on the rotating planet's position.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured I'd just write up a solution using the `<canvas>`

```js
var x, y, scale, state,  // Variables we'll use later.
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"), // Get the canvas,
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),             // And it's context.
    counter = 0,          // Counter to increment for the sin / cos functions.
    width = 350,          // Canvas width.
    height = 200,         // Canvas height.
    centerX = width / 2,  // X-axis center position.
    centerY = height / 2, // Y-axis center position.
    orbit = {             // Settings for the orbiting planet:
      width: 150,         //   Orbit width,
      height: 50,         //   Orbit height,
      size: 10            //   Orbiting planet's size.
    };

canvas.width = width;   // Set the width and height of the canvas.
canvas.height = height;

function update(){
  state = counter / 75; // Decrease the speed of the planet for a nice smooth animation.
  x = centerX + Math.sin(state) * orbit.width;  // Orbiting planet x position.
  y = centerY + Math.cos(state) * orbit.height; // Orbiting planet y position.
  scale = (Math.cos(state) + 2) * orbit.size;  // Orbiting planet size.

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height); // Clear the canvas

  // If the orbiting planet is before the center one, draw the center one first.
  (y > centerY) && drawPlanet();
  drawPlanet("#f00", x, y, scale); // Draw the orbiting planet.
  (y <= centerY) && drawPlanet();

  counter++;
}

// Draw a planet. Without parameters, this will draw a black planet at the center.
function drawPlanet(color, x, y, size){
  ctx.fillStyle = color || "#000";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x || centerX,
          y || centerY,
          size || 50,
          0,
          Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.fill();
}

// Execute `update` every 10 ms.
setInterval(update, 10);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

If you want to change the roation direction of the orbiting planet, just replace:

```
x = centerX + Math.sin(state) * orbit.width;
y = centerY + Math.cos(state) * orbit.height;
```

With:

```
x = centerX + Math.cos(state) * orbit.width;
y = centerY + Math.sin(state) * orbit.height;
//                  ^ Those got switched.
```

The speed of the orbit can be changed by modifying the `75` in:

```
state = counter / 75;
```

Comment: basic math, basic programming, so pretty ^^

Comment: I'm very new to JavaScript - thank you so much for including explanations in your code.

Comment: Could you have orbiting text instead of the red planet?

Comment: Sure, just draw text instead of the arc, @gillespieza